# Read a text file with non-ASCII characters in an unknown encoding

Tags: python, encoding

I want to read a file that contains also **German and not only characters**. I found that i can do like this

```
  >>> import codecs
  >>> file = codecs.open('file.txt','r', encoding='UTF-8')
  >>> lines= file.readlines()
```

This is working when i try to run my job in Python IDLE but when i try to run it from somewhere else does not give correct result. Have a idea?

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: It depends what encoding the file was saved with. iso8859-1 is probably good guess if it's not UTF-8.

Comment: python3.1. Really how we see the current version we use?

Comment: @indiag, [`sys.version`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.version) or [`sys.version_info`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.version_info).

Comment: Again it is not working with iso8859-1. I have the characters ö,ü,ä,ß

Comment: ok thanks. This is my version                                                               3.1 (r31:73574, Jun 26 2009, 17:50:52) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]

Comment: @indiag, Try reading the file in binary mode using `open('file.txt', 'rb').readlines()`, and then use `print(repr(line))` for a line that you know contains the German characters, as well as what you expect it to be.  This should help us determine what the encoding is.

Comment: sorry. It is not contains only German characters. Exists also a name Božović. It is like a phone book

Comment: @F.J it is not working again. I ll post a part of the text file

Comment: sorry guys i do not know now is working                               lines = codecs.open('fbc_math.txt','r', encoding='UTF-8').readlines()

Comment: @indiag, it just occurred to me that `readlines()` probably doesn't work in binary mode, try `print(repr(open('file.txt', 'rb').read()))`, and then post all or a portion of the output.

Comment: @F.J this that you suggest give me strange results. I do not know

Comment: @indiag If you found the solution to your problem, it would be better to post this as an answer, not as an edition in your question. Post it as an answer and accept it.

Comment: @brandizzi ok i ll do it. But this working only from python IDLE. I ll change the question.

Comment: You need to better define what you mean by "not working". Is it giving an error, or are the wrong characters being displayed?

Comment: @MarkRansom when i run the program in linux print this special characters with some strange form BoΕΎoviΔ, Nemanja and when i run it in windows by cmd it gives a message 'return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)'

Answer (score 23):

You need to know which character encoding the text is encoded in. If you don't know that beforehand, you can try guessing it with the [chardet](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet) module. First install it:

```
$ pip install chardet
```

Then, for example reading the file in binary mode:

```
>>> import chardet
>>> chardet.detect(open("file.txt", "rb").read())
{'confidence': 0.9690625, 'encoding': 'utf-8'}
```

So then:

```
>>> import codecs
>>> import unicodedata
>>> lines = codecs.open('file.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8').readlines()
```

Comment: You have to import codecs at the top of your file: `import codecs`

Answer (score 0):

I believe the file is being read correctly but is using the wrong encoding when output. This is based on the fact that you get the proper results in IDLE.

I would suggest trying to use `print(line.encode('utf-8'))` but I'm afraid I don't know if Python 3 will print a `bytes` object properly.